# Configuring Webservice.dll into IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2008, iis-5

I'm creating web service by through

File->New Project->web->ASP.Net Web Service Application.

Instead of File->New Website->ASP.Net Web Service Application.

After Coding and building Project, I got the web service Link library,

Here my question is how to deploy Link library into the IIS.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't be doing any new development using ASMX web services, unless you have no choice. You should be using WCF instead.

Second, depending on which version of Visual Studio you are using (and you didn't tell us), you should be able to right-click the application and choose Publish.

Comment: Thanks to reply john, I'm not going for WCF. I just need my dll have to work like web service accessible to other developers need service from my web service link library.

Comment: Just so long as you know you are going against Microsoft recommendations, go right ahead.